# Ant ReplaceRegExp Questions

Tags: xml, ant, force.com

I'm new to the ReplaceRegExp function in Ant, and have some questions.

Here is my use case.

I have multiple .xml files, which I need to manipulate in specific ways.

Here is one example of the .xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>29.0</apiVersion>
    <packageVersions>
        <majorNumber>1</majorNumber>
        <minorNumber>1228</minorNumber>
        <namespace>prefix1__FirstNamespace</namespace>
    </packageVersions>
    <packageVersions>
        <majorNumber>2</majorNumber>
        <minorNumber>4</minorNumber>
        <namespace>prefix2__TheNextNamespace</namespace>
    </packageVersions>
    <packageVersions>
        <majorNumber>7</majorNumber>
        <minorNumber>542</minorNumber>
        <namespace>prefix3__AnotherNamespace</namespace>
    </packageVersions>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

How can I update the the  &  attributes of the  only where the  attribute contains the prefix "prefix3"?

I've tried this function, hoping to change the  attribute to the value specified by ${correctMinorNumber}:

```
<target name="setminorNumber">
    <replaceregexp  flags="gis" 
                    match="&lt;minorNumber&gt;?(.*)&lt;/minorNumber&gt;?(.+?)&lt;namespace&gt;prefix3__&lt;/namespace&gt;"
                    byline="false"
        >
        <substitution expression="&lt;minorNumber&gt;${correctMinorNumber}&lt;/minorNumber&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&lt;namespace&gt;prefix3__&lt;/namespace&gt;"/>
        <fileset dir="${sf.retrieveFolder}">
            <include name="**/*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

It worked correct on files where there was only one `<packageVersion>` node (with prefix3__ in the namespace), but on files containing multiple `<packageVersion>` nodes it replaces all nodes with one prefix3__ node. I'm guessing the problem lies with my use of the wildcard, but I don't know enough about replaceregexp to identify the correct solution.

Any ideas on what I can do to achieve what I need to do?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing XML with regular expressions is [fraught with problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/1078068) and best avoided.

Instead, consider using [XMLTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/). It's an Ant task dedicated to parsing and modifying XML.

Download xmltask.jar and put it in the Ant `lib` directory.

Below is part of an Ant script. It identifies `<minorNumber>` elements that are siblings of `<namespace>` elements where the `<namespace>` elements have a text node starting with the string `prefix3__`. It then replaces the text node under the `<minorNumber>` element:

```
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask" />

<xmltask dest="${dest.xml-file}">
    <fileset file="src.xml"/>
    <replace 
        path="//:packageVersions[starts-with(:namespace/text(), 'prefix3__')]/:minorNumber/text()" 
        withText="${correctMinorNumber}"
    />
</xmltask>
```

This script assumes that the XML is in a file named `src.xml` and a property named `dest.xml-file` points to where the modified of XML should go.

Comment: Thank you for this, it looks very promising! One question, will this work will multiple .xml files in a directory? Or is there a way to iterate through all the files & run this task for each?

Comment: `<xmltask>` takes a `<fileset>` that can process several files with one call: `<xmltask todir="output"><fileset dir="."><includes name="*.xml"/>`

Comment: Yep that's what I found earlier and it worked, thanks a million for your help!